# Can't force overflow-x: visible

Tags: css

I have container with following styles:

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:visible;
position:relative;
```

Inside I have table with following styles:

```
position:relative;
```

For some reason I still see both scrollbars (x and y). I can't force x scrollbar to disappear.
I can't put in to fiddle for now because of lots of scripts and so on but I will do it soon...
Anyway when I check container in chrome it has `overflow-x: visible` and scrollbar is visible - how it is possible???

edit -----------------

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncd2Y/1/
why x scrollbar is visible???

Guys I want the content to be visible on x axis...
Content has to be visible (outside container) and scrollbar not visible...

Comment: Is your content larger than div with overflow? Will `overflow-x:hidden;` solve the problem?

Comment: Yes hidden hides the content but I want it to be visible...

Comment: Does this mean you have to extend the div also or only display the content??

Comment: when you exclude the table from the div you can wrap arround another relative container to chain them together like in the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncd2Y/3/

Answer (score 2):

it is visible because its css property is visible

```
.css({"overflow-y":"hidden","overflow-x":"hidden"});
```

will remove all scrollbars.

your css:

```
#container {
background:green;

width:100px;
height:100px;
display:block;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

}​

to achieve your final goal, you should exclude the table from the container and positionin it absolute above and z index it lower than the table: see your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ncd2Y/2/

your workarround css

```
#container {
background:green;
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:block;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
word-wrap: break-word;
z-index: -10;
```

}​

and worarround html:

```
  <div id="container">

</div>
 <table id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>column</td>
                <td>column</td>
                <td>column</td>
                <td>column</td>
                <td>column</td>
                <td>column</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>            
    </table>
​
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-x: visible` will result in the content being visible.  `overflow-x: hidden` will hide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

will solve problem..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Don't waste time. Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bugfix = document.createElement('style')
    bugfix.innerHTML = "body {overflow-x: hidden !important;}";
    document.body.appendChild(bugfix);
  });
```